# How to add a bootstrap script to tox's virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, psycopg2, setup.py, tox

I need psycopg2 and lxml for my tests, but when I try to install it in a virtualenv through tox it fails due to the missing pg_conf or other dependencies.

I found this explanation of bootstrap scripts: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#bootstrap-example

How can I add a bootstrap script to tox's virtualenv? Do you know any good examples for my concerns (lxml and psycopg2)?

Comment: I had the exact same problem and tried various ways to solve it reliably. Whether `pg_config` is on `$PATH` or not also depends on the OS and how Postgres was installed. In the end I decided to just put `pg_config` on my $PATH from my `.profile` and be done with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t think you can use bootstrap scripts (as described in the virtualenv docs) with tox. However, you can configure your `tox.ini` file to install Python dependencies that are not specified in `setup.py`, and run arbitrary commands before running tests. From the tox home page:

```
# content of: tox.ini , put in same dir as setup.py
[tox]
envlist = py26,py27
[testenv]
deps=pytest       # install pytest in the venvs
commands=py.test  # or 'nosetests' or ...
```

`deps` and `commands` are actually lists:

```
deps=
    lxml
    psycopg2
    pytest
commands=
    ./some_other_script.sh
    py.test
```

But forget about bootstrap scripts and take a step back. What is the original problem with pg_conf?